# Angular, how to walk form children?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I visit all fields in my form? I would like to do something like the below, but haven't been able to find a way to do this, possibly it's not supported by Angular?

```
var form = ctrl.editform;

function walkForm(form) {

  for (child in form.children)
      if (child instanceof form)
          walkForm(child);
      else
          visit(child);
}
```

Comment: why tagged angular cant see anything related to angular?

Comment: asking if Angular provides a way to accomplish this?

Comment: ok so what do you actually want to achieve. because there might be some other way that may help you achieve that

Comment: @ab11 what version of `angularjs` are you using?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash 1.5.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following function to touch everything on an angular material form using lodash which may help?

```
function touchForm(form) {
    return $timeout(function () {
            if (!form) return;
            var filtered = _.filter(Object.keys(form), function(key) {
                return key.indexOf('$') !== 0;
            });

            _.forEach(filtered, function(n) {
                var control = form[n];                    
                if (control.hasOwnProperty('$setTouched')) {
                    control.$setTouched();
                } else if (control.hasOwnProperty('$submitted')) // is a nested form
                {
                    touchForm(control);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks helpful, doesn't work for me, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to work. When I call this function with my form object, it exits before executing the `_.filter` (this code prints '1' and '2' , but not '3' or '4': https://jsfiddle.net/rdwzdxb3/).  I'm not sure why `_.filter` doesn't execute, also not sure how `form[n]` is supposed to work, `form` is a form object not an array?

Comment: You can reference object properties using their names as if they were an array. So you get hold of the properties that don't start with $ on the form. For each of these property values, if they have $setTouched call it, if it has $submitted treat it as an inner form and recursively  call it.

Comment: I understand, can similar functionality be accomplished without lodash?

Comment: I think you can even omit using `lodash` and iterate over all the form properties like `angular.forEach(form, function (value, key) {
        if (!!value && angular.isObject(value) && value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
            console.log(value); // we have a form control here
        }          
    });` if you are using [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive on the form controls.